# Porting Linux on LPC2148 board

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-installation, arm

Till now I was working with Raspberry pi, beaglebone etc. So, I am looking to do something new. So, I decide to port Linux on my LPC2148 board. But I am unable to find any tutorial regarding linux porting on LPC2148 board. So, is it even possible to port linux on LPC2148 board? if yes, then please provide me some details.

Answer (score 2):

Since the chip is a arm7 device, it should be possible in general. But as the device has VERY small ram/flash storage and no mmu, no full-featured linux will run there.
Have a look here: https://uclinux2015.hackpad.com/ That's a similar project.